# .dll file integration in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I am having a .dll file which has a wrapper in C,C++, .Net and python, but not in Java. I am successful in loading the .dll file using following code in my Java

```
public class 

    public static void main(String[] {
        // print when the program starts
        System.out.println("Program starting...");

        System.out.println("Loading Library...");

        Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("HelloJava");

        System.out.println("Library Loaded.");
    }
}
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Now my question is that if this file is loaded, How do I access it's functions to use in my Java workspace?
Since it is the C-DLL, so How should I fetch the module values from this .dll.

Note:

- I have made a folder named dll under my Java project path from where I loaded the library in the above code.
- I browsed for the concept for JNA and JNI but lacked the understanding concept, that's why posted the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to know the methods in your DLL first. I really don't know how to list the methods using JNA or JNI, but you have to know the method's signature before starting, maybe from a documentation, because you normally can find the DLL's documentation on the web, or you even can use a Reflector (like red-gate) to find out your methods.

Then:

1. Download the JNA .jar file and add it to your build in your Java project.
2. Put the .dll in the root directory of your Java project.
3. Create an Interface that contains the functions from the dll that you want to use.

   For example, lets say your HelloWorld DLL has a String hello(String hey) method in C++, then in your Java project you will have to do something like:

   ```
   import com.sun.jna.Library;
   import com.sun.jna.Native;

   public class Main {
       public interface Ihello extends Library {
           public String hello(String hey);
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           //"hello-world is the name my DLL, for example.
           Hello h = Native.load("hello-world", Hello.class);

           System.out.println(h.hello(" John! ");
       }
   }
   ```

[Here](https://shansvex.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/using-a-dll-in-java-with-jna-java-native-access/) is a good example, regards.

Comment: Thankyou. I'll try your solution and comeback to you. :)